# Find Linear Map between Majorized Vectors

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, majorization

Suppose I am given two vectors, $x, y$ such that $x\prec y$ ($x$ is [majorized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majorization#:%7E:text=From%20Wikipedia%2C%20the%20free%20encyclopedia,but%20sorted%20in%20descending%20order.) by $y$). Suppose further that these are infinite dimensional vectors, such that $\sum_i x_i = \sum_i y_i = 1$, and they are already arranged in decreasing order. We know as a consequence of the majorization relation that we can write $x = Dy$, where $D$ is a doubly stochastic matrix ($\sum_i a_{ij} = \sum_j a_{ij} = 1$, $a_{i,j} \geq 0 \ \forall \ i,j$ ). Is it possible to analytically find $D$? If so, is there some continuous-variable method than we can use to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is a general procedure for solving this problem. We have two sequences $x = (x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n)$ and $y = (y_1, y_2, \cdots, y_n)$ such that $x\prec y$. Suppose these are already in descending order (if not, a permutation of the vectors yields the desired ordering). First, we identify that the following two conditions are true:

$$
y_n \leq x_1 \leq y_1 \\
y_k \leq x_1 \leq y_{k-1},
$$

for some $k$. We can thus write:

$$
x_1 = t_1y_1 + (1-t_1)y_k
$$

and define new vectors $x^{'}, y^{'}$ such that:

$$
x^{'} = (x_2, \cdots, x_n)\\
y^{'} = (x_2, \cdots, y_{k-1}, (1-t_1)y_1 + t_1y_k, y_{k+1}, \cdots x_n)
$$

Now, we can write

$$
y^{'}_n \leq x^{1}_1 \leq y^{1}_1 \\
y^{'}_j \leq x^{1}_1 \leq y^{'}_{j-1},
$$

for some index $j$. We can thus write:

$$
x^{'}_1 = t_2y^{'}_1 + (1-t_2)y^{'}_j
$$

Now we may define new vectors $x^{''}, y^{''}$ such that:

$$
x^{''} = (x_3, \cdots, x_n)\\
y^{''} = (x_3, \cdots, y_{j-1}, (1-t_2)y_1 + t_2y_j, y_{j+1}, \cdots, y_{k-1}, (1-t_1)y_1 + t_1y_k, y_{k+1}, \cdots x_n)
$$

This procedure thus continues until we can write $x = Dy$, where $D$ is a doubly stochastic matrix ($\sum_i a_{ij} = \sum_j a_{ij} = 1$, $a_{i,j} \geq 0 \ \forall \ i,j$) comprised of T-transforms, i.e. $D = T_r\cdots T_2 T_1$. T-transforms act on just 2 components of a vector, and act as the identity on all other components; these have the form:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
t&1-t\\
1-t & t
\end{bmatrix}
$$

These transforms can be thought of as convex combinations of the identity map and a permutation; thus, $D$ is a convex combination of the identity map and permutations.

---

Let's consider an example:

$$
x = (5, 3, 2)\\
y = (6, 3, 1)
$$

We have that:

$$
y_n = 1 \leq x_1 = 5 \leq y_1 = 6\\
y_k = y_2 = 3 \leq x_1 = 5 \leq y_{k-1} = y_1 = 6
$$

Therefore, we have that

$$
5 = x_1 = t_1y_1 + (1-t_1)y_k = 6t_1 + 3(1-t_1)\\
\therefore t_1 = \frac{2}{3}
$$

We now consider the reduced vectors:

$$
x^{'} = (3, 2)\\
y^{'} = ((1-t_1)y_1 + t_1y_k, 1) = ((\frac{1}{3})\cdot6 + \frac{2}{3}\cdot3, 1) = (4,1)
$$

Note that $x^{'}\prec y^{'}$. Solving for the second t-parameter:

$$
y^{'}_n = 1 \leq x^{'}_1 = 3 \leq y^{'}_1 = 4\\
y^{'}_k = y^{'}_2 = 1 \leq x^{'}_1 = 3 \leq y^{'}_{k-1} = y^{'}_1 = 4\\
3 = x^{'}_1 = t_2y^{'}_1 + (1-t_2)y^{'}_k = 4t_2 + 1(1-t_2)\\
\therefore t_2 = \frac{2}{3}
$$

Now note that:

$$
x^{''} = (2)\\
y^{''} = ((1-t_2)y^{'}_1 + t_2y^{'}_k) = ((\frac{2}{3})\cdot4 + \frac{2}{3}\cdot2) = (2)
$$

Hence, we have solved for the overall transformation matrix:

$$
x = Dy = T_2 T_1 y\\
\begin{pmatrix}5\\3\\2 \end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0&t_2&1-t_2\\
0&1-t_2 & t_2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
t_1&1-t_1 &0\\
1-t_1 & t_1&0\\
0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}6\\3\\1 \end{pmatrix}
$$